# Sync dropbox to native iPad folder?

Tags: ipad, dropbox

I have a Dropbox account, and an iPad.  How do I sync the Dropbox account to a native folder on the iPad so that I don't have to manually open the Dropbox app to open/edit a file, find attachments for emails, etc.?

Comment: As there's no native file system access on iOS, there's no easy way to answer this question since that is the missing piece. Do you want to edit this question to ask that overarching topic or perhaps edit it to a specific case? Many apps integrate dropbox but it's a one by one solution to meet your particular needs.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you jailbreak your device, you don't have direct access to the file system on iOS.
I think you should continue to use the Dropbox App to access your files.

If you want an jailbroken alternative, I let someone else answer because I'm not an jailbreak expert :-)

Hope this helps !